# Am I including these JavaScript files correctly?

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel

I just want to know if this is reasonably good implementation of including local/remote JavaScript files.

The function takes a dictionary with (string) `.src` whitespace-separated list of urls to include/execute in global context, and (func) `.done/.error/.load` callbacks to run in corresponding cases, resolves URLs  to absolute, temporarily inserts `<script>` blocks in page header, caches loaded addresses, and attaches few static properties: (object) `.defaults` and (func) `.ls/.reload` to main `includejs()` function.

```
// #includejs
;((function (name, def) {
  this[name] = def(document);
}).call(
  this, "includejs", function (doc) {

  // will be used to reference private includejs() version
  var _include;

  // holds cached script urls
  var imported = {};

  // no-op callback default
  var pass = function () {};

  // helpers
  var _ = {

    // <a> helper element to resolve urls to absolute
    anchor: doc.createElement("a"), 

    // calculates difference of two arrays
    // used by includejs() to filter new urls to load
    arrdiff: function (a1, a2) {
      return a1.filter(_.cbuniq).filter(_.cbdiff, a2);
    }, 

    // calculates intersection of two arrays
    // used by includejs.reload() to filter cached urls
    arrinters: function (a1, a2) {
      return a1.filter(_.cbuniq).filter(_.cbinters, a2);
    }, 
    cbdiff: function (node) {
      //this: a2[]
      return this.indexOf(node) == -1;
    }, 
    cbinters: function (node) {
      //this: a2[]
      return this.indexOf(node) != -1;
    }, 
    cbpropcp: function (name) {
      //this: {src{}, target{}}
      this.target[name] = this.src[name];
    }, 
    cbrmprop: function (name) {
      //this: target{}
      try {
        delete this[name];
      } catch (e) {}
    }, 
    cbuniq: function (node, idx, arr) {
      return idx <= arr.indexOf(node);
    }, 

    // shallow copies an (object) node
    // used by includejs.ls() to list cached urls
    cp: function (node) {
      var nodecp = {};
      _.keys(node).forEach(_.cbpropcp, {src: node, target: nodecp});
      return nodecp;
    }, 

    // default settup
    defs: {

      src   : "", 

      done  : pass, 
      error : pass,
      load  : pass

    }, 

    // removes passed properties from (object) node
    // used in includejs.reload() to filter cached urls
    del: function (node) { //, ...props
      _.arrinters(_.keys(imported), _.slc(arguments, 1))
      .forEach(_.cbrmprop, node);
      return node;
    }, 
    // helper for wssplit() for filter out empty strings
    fnid: function (node) {
      return node;
    }, 

    // <head> reference for temporarily injecting <script>-s
    h: doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], 

    // attaches properties of (object) items to (object) target
    // used in few places to assign object properties
    init: function (target, items) {
      for (var name in items) {
        if (items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          target[name] = items[name];
        }
      }
      return target;
    }, 
    isfn: function (node) {
      return "function" == typeof node;
    }, 
    isplainobj: function (node) {
      return "[object Object]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(node);
    }, 
    isstr: function (node) {
      return "[object String]" == Object.prototype.toString.call(node);
    },
    keys: function (node) {
      return Object.keys(Object(node));
    }, 
    now: Date.now, 

    // calculates absolute url coresponding to given (string) url
    // not sure if this works on old ies
    path2abs: function (url) {
      _.anchor.href = ""+ url;
      return _.anchor.href;
    }, 

    // matches whitespace globaly
    // copy-pasted from es5-shim.js
    // https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git
    rews: /[\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x20\xA0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000\u2028\u2029\uFEFF]+/g, 

    // used for converting dynamic arguments object to static array
    slc: function () {
      return Array.prototype.slice.apply(Array.prototype.shift.call(arguments), arguments);
    }, 

    // empties an object
    // used in includejs.reload() to empty private url cache 
    // forcing reload 
    vacate: function (node) {
      for (var name in node) {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          delete node[name];
        }
      }
      return node;
    }, 

    // splits whitespace-separated string to it's components
    // returns array of uniqe (string) urls
    // used by includejs() to turn (string) .src urls to array
    wssplit: function (str) {
      return (""+ str).split(_.rews).filter(_.cbuniq).filter(_.fnid);
    }
  };


  // main function
  _include = function (settup) {

    var opts = {};

    _.isplainobj(settup) || (settup = {});

    // take only uncached absolute script urls
    opts.src = 
    _.arrdiff(
      _.wssplit(_.isstr(settup.src) ? settup.src : "").map(_.path2abs), 
      _.keys(imported)
    );

    opts.done  = _.isfn(settup.done)  ? settup.done  : _.defs.done;
    opts.error = _.isfn(settup.error) ? settup.error : _.defs.error;
    opts.load  = _.isfn(settup.load)  ? settup.load  : _.defs.load;

    // acts as counter to track download progress
    opts.i   = 0;

    // holds <script> nodes for caching, and for callback clean-up afterward
    opts.s   = [];

    // for tracking download progress, when opts.i == opts.len download is done
    opts.len = opts.src.length;

    if (opts.len) {
      opts.src.forEach(_requireloadcb, opts);
    } else {
      // asyncs _requireloadcompletecb()
      setTimeout(function () {
        _requireloadcompletecb(opts);
      });
    }

    return opts.src.slice(0);
  };


  // export
  // adds 'includejs' function identifier to global scope
  return _.init(_include, {

    defaults: _.defs, 

    // query cached urls
    ls: function () {
      return _.cp(imported);
    }, 

    // reloads cached .src urls 
    // takes same-format-object as includejs()
    reload: function (settup) {

      if (_.isstr(settup)) 
      settup = {src: settup};

      _.isplainobj(settup) || (settup = {});

      if (!settup.hasOwnProperty("src")) {
        settup.src = _.keys(imported).join(" ");
        _.vacate(imported);
      } else {
        _.del.apply(null, 
          [imported]
          .concat(_.wssplit(_.isstr(settup.src) ? settup.src : "").map(_.path2abs))
        );
      }

      _include(settup);
    }
  });


  // helpers

  // nulls .onload/.onerror handlers
  // detaches loaded <script> node
  // used by _requireloadcompletecb() to perform cleanup
  function _requiregcloadcb (nodescript) {
    nodescript.onload  = null;
    nodescript.onerror = null;
    _.h.removeChild(nodescript);
  }

  // generates new <script> and appends it to  <head> 
  // executing <script>.src file in global context
  // used by includejs() to download/execute script files
  function _requireloadcb (fileurl) {
    //this: {src, done, error, load, i, len, s}
    var opts = this;
    var nodescript = _.init(doc.createElement("script"), {

      onerror : function () { // ...e
        //this: <script>
        opts.i += 1;
        opts.error.apply(this, arguments);
        _requireloadcompletecb(opts);
      },
      onload  : function () { // ...e
        //this: <script>
        opts.i += 1;
        imported[fileurl] = _.now();
        opts.load.apply(this, arguments);
        _requireloadcompletecb(opts);
      }, 

      defer : false, 
      src   : fileurl, 
      type  : "application/javascript"

     });

    //opts.s.push(_.h.removeChild(_.h.appendChild(nodescript)));
    opts.s.push(_.h.appendChild(nodescript));
  }

  // cleans up after scripts load/fail-to-load 
  // nulls .onload/.onerror handlers
  // empties settup (object) opts
  function _requireloadcompletecb (opts) {
    if (opts.i == opts.len) {
      opts.done.apply(doc, opts.src);
      opts.s.forEach(_requiregcloadcb);
      // opts.s.splice(0, 1/0);
      opts.s.splice(0);
      _.vacate(opts);
    }
  }

}
));
//
// use:
//   
//   includejs({
//     src: "lib/_.js //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js", 
//     done: function (scripturls) {
//       // _doStuff(scripturls);
//       console.log("done", this, arguments);
//     }, 
//     load: function (e) {
//       // _srcLoaded(this);
//       console.log(e, this);
//     }, 
//     error: function (e) {
//       // _srcFailed(this);
//       console.log(e, this);
//     }
//   });
//   
//  // console:
//  load <script src="http://localhost/sites/xsite/lib/_.js" type="application/javascript">
//  load <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js" type="application/javascript">
//  done Document index.htm ["http://localhost/sites/xsite/lib/_.js", "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.../2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"]
//  
//  console.log(includejs.ls());
//  // console:
//  Object { 
//    http://localhost/sites/xsite/lib/_.js = 1394306633258, 
//    http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js = 1394306633369
//  }
//  
//  includejs.reload({
//    done: function (urls) {
//      // _doStuffOnReload(urls);
//      console.log("reloaded", this, arguments);
//    }
//  });
//  
//  // console:
//  reloaded Document index.htm ["http://localhost/sites/xsite/lib/_.js", "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.../2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"]
//
```

Comment: There are many script loader libraries out there, some extremely small and simple.  What new functionality are you offering over all these other offerings.  Or put another way, what benefit do you have to reinventing a solution that has been offered in many tried/true libraries?  Here's one for comparison: http://labjs.com/.

Comment: Yes, there are dozens of tested solutions out there, there's nothing new and extraordinary revolutionary in this peace of code I've posted. I was hoping to get/implement critics for this implementation because it is critical in javascript utility library I'm working on...

Comment: I'd suggest that maybe you write up a list of features it has.  As your question is now, we're left to try to discern from the code what it is supposed to do and then try to evaluate how well it does that.  I rather doubt you will get much feedback without providing a lot more info.  And, why can't you use an existing, tested, supported open source library that already exists in your own utility library?  Why rewrite from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is interesting,

you are clearly smart and know JavaScript, but this is a maintenance nightmare. I am assuming you will not take my advice to heart but here goes:

- Do not abbreviate: `isfn` -> `isFunction`, `isstr` -> `isString`, `cbpropcp` -> ? ,`slc` -> `slice`, `_requiregcloadcb` -> ? etc. etc. etc. etc.
- Also, use lowerCamelCase
- Also, avoid `_xx` for private variables, as per Crockford
- Name functions for what they do, not how they are used:

  ```
  fnid: function (node) {
    return node;
  },
  ```

  `fnid` is a terrible name, if possible I would refactor the code so that I would not need this function. A better name might be `value` ?
- JSHint could not find anything wrong, except that your event handlers do not use `e`, so you do not need to declare `e` as a parameter
- You use `cbrmprop` and similar functions only once, consider in-lining them
- `settup` -> `setup` ;)
- `opts.s.splice(0, 1/0);` -> `opts.s.splice();`
- `defer : false,` -> I think this should have been an option

Comment: Fully private variables as per Crockford: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html -- I see that as problematic though because each time you create a new object, a new set of functions and variables are created when really only the variables should be duplicated. Not having such private variables means lighter code... right?

Comment: It's more that `_` does not do anything in the language, and it's one more version of Hungarian notation in a way. Trying to find a link..